# Putting bat file inside a jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file

I have a java class that uses a bat file to execute commands. However I developed it in Eclipse IDE. It works fine in there. But as I export it in a jar file, it fails to find the bat file that was included.(gives me an IOException)

The file structure in eclipse is as follows
:

```
Project1
---->src
------>com.myproj
-------->BatFileRead.java
----md.bat
----ul.bat
```

md.bat and ul.bat is same level as src directory. After jarring it src folder disappears.

Could someone help me with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In order to execute the command, you'll have to extract the bat file afterwards. You can't run executables which are inside jar files. Basically you'll need to open the batch file entry in the jar file as an input stream, and copy the data to a `FileOutputStream` on disk. You won't be able to execute it until it's a proper standalone file on the file system.

If you're already trying to extract it, chances are you're using `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream` slightly incorrectly. This is easy to do, because it depends whether you're calling `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` or `Class.getResourceAsStream`. The first only ever uses absolute paths (implicitly) and the second can use either absolute or relative paths. For example, in your case you'd want:

```
BatFileRead.class.getResourceAsStream("/md.bat")
```

or

```
BatFileRead.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("md.bat")
```

Have you checked that the bat files are definitely ending up in the jar file? Just list the contents with

```
jar tvf file.jar
```

to see what's in there.

Comment: I have checked it the bat files are in there. Well i use

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("md.bat"); to execute the bat file  inside my class.

Comment: Well that's certainly not going to work unless you extract them. The Windows command shell doesn't understand jar files.

Answer (score 1):

Well this can be very dangerous. Be sure to use gloves when dealing with the BAT. They bite and quite painfull. Also try getting jar that has a big enough opening, although the bats will fit almost through any hole.

Good luck, and don't try this at home. This is done by professionals.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying `file.jar` to `file.zip`, and opening `file.zip` (e.g. just double clicking, or using e.g. 7-Zip). Can you find your `.bat` files inside? If the `.bat` file isn't there, you have to add the `.bat` file to your Eclipse project, and rebuild in Eclipse. If the `.bat` file is there, but you still get an `IOException` opening it from you `.java` application, then please post the code snippet triggering the `IOException`, and please give a full listing of `file.zip` (get the listing by extracting `file.zip` to `C:\testdir`, and running `dir /s C:\testdir` in the command line).

Please note that Jon Skeet is right that although it is possible to open any file in the `.jar` file as an `InputStream` using `java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream` and `java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` (see [tutorial](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/getresourceasstream.html) or find them in the [Java API docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/)), but in order to execute a `.bat` file inside, you have to extract the `.jar` file first.

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ul.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:459)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:431)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:328)
        at com.myproj.BatFileRead.execute(BatFileRead.java:38)

using this to execute the bat file : 

exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ul.bat");